# emulation vs simulation

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between simulation and emulation. I am particularly interested in their difference within a computer science context but would also like to understand it properly from a linguistic point of view.

ciao 
Andrea

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to put example usages or context. Otherwise, your question might be closed for lack of research/reference. Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134746/whats-the-difference-between-simulation-and-emulation

Comment: In a lexicographical nutshell, to simulate is to pretend to be the same as something, and to emulate is to try to match or exceed something. A dictionary will probably serve you better than a nutshell, though.

Comment: @JEL what if the dictionary fits in a nutshell?

Comment: @michael_timofeev, then the nutshell and the dictionary both may need to be cracked.

Comment: @JEL ok, we better simmer down, otherwise we'll be scolded.

Answer (score 1):

To answer from a computer science perspective:

1) A simulator is a program which models something else.  An example would be a program that takes as input a mathematical description of an airplane wing and analyzes wind tunnel airflow around it.  The simulator is simulating a real-world wind tunnel.  Simulators are used as predictive tools that can provide answers without doing a real-world experiment.

2) An emulator is a program that enables a computer to pretend it is something else.  An example would be a Windows program that allows a Windows machine to execute old Atari video games.   Emulators are not predictive tools.  Emulators enable running of programs intended for different hardware or software than the machine on which the program runs.